# how to get specific json object from json array using angular 8

Tags: angular

I am showing a list from json and it has a click button which is returning me whole particular row object.
I want to get only specific json object using Angular 8.

```
     <table class="table1">
      <tr>
      <th>Job Name</th>
      <th>Job Type</th>
      <!-- <th>Immediate Priority</th> -->
      <th>Start Time</th>
      <th>Available Hywa</th>
      <th>Required Hywa</th>
      </tr>
     <tr *ngFor="let obj of jobActivity">
      <td>{{obj.csctsJob.jobName}}</td>
      <td>{{obj.csctsJob.jobType}}</td>
      <!-- <td>{{obj.csctsJob.immediatePriority}}</td> -->
      <td>{{obj.csctsJob.startTimeline | date:'medium'}}</td>
      <td>{{obj.csctsJob.availHywa}}</td>
      <td>{{obj.csctsJob.reqHywa}}</td>
      <td>
          <span class="btn1 btn-xs" (click)="onEditJobAllocation(obj)">
            <img src="/assets/edit-24px.svg" alt="edit">
          </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

app.component.ts

```
   onEditJobAllocation(obj){
    console.log(obj);
    }
```

it is returning me all other object also but i want to only specific object without forloop or push method please help me out.
I am getting my json like this.

```
csctsJobActivityList:[
 { activityId: "ACT_1",
   capacity: 100,
  completedCapacity: 0,
  createTimestamp: "2019-12-09T08:05:14.369+0000" ,
  createUser: "mahan_admin" ,
  fromStock: "STOCK_8",
  jobId: "JOB_6",
 reqHywa: null,
 status: "INA" ,
 toStock: "STOCK_10",
 updateTimestamp: null },
 {activityId: "ACT_1",
capacity: 100,
completedCapacity: 0,
createTimestamp: "2019-12-09T08:05:14.369+0000" ,
createUser: "mahan_admin",
fromStock: "STOCK_8",
jobId: "JOB_6",
reqHywa: null ,
status: "INA",
toStock: "STOCK_10" ,
updateTimestamp: null }]
```

I want my json to be like this without using forLoop or push method.

```
  csctsJobActivityList:[
    { activityId: "ACT_1",
    capacity: 100,
    fromStock: "STOCK_8",
    jobId: "JOB_6",
    reqHywa: null,
    status: "INA" ,
    toStock: "STOCK_10",
     },

   {activityId: "ACT_1",
   capacity: 100,
   fromStock: "STOCK_8",
   jobId: "JOB_6",
   reqHywa: null ,
   status: "INA",
   toStock: "STOCK_10" ,
    }]
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. I think it would be helpful if you could share a minimal sample code that replicates the issue. You can fork a project on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) and update it with minimal code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: can you show us your json and the result you are expecting ?

Comment: csctsJobActivityList:[{
activityId: "ACT_1"
capacity: 100
completedCapacity: 0
createTimestamp: "2019-12-09T08:05:14.369+0000"
createUser: "mahan_admin"
fromStock: "STOCK_8"
jobId: "JOB_6"
reqHywa: null
status: "INA"
toStock: "STOCK_10"
updateTimestamp: null
},
{0:
activityId: "ACT_1"
capacity: 100
completedCapacity: 0
createTimestamp: "2019-12-09T08:05:14.369+0000"
createUser: "mahan_admin"
fromStock: "STOCK_8"
jobId: "JOB_6"
reqHywa: null
status: "INA"
toStock: "STOCK_10"
updateTimestamp: null
}]
I want only  fromStock,toStock,activityId,capacity

Comment: Post your json in the main question (using the "Edit" link) *not* as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will return only the properties related to `csctsJob` and not others which may be present in your `obj`.

```
(click)="onEditJobAllocation(obj.csctsJob)
```